# put the result of sql select statement into variable in C

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I'm writing a C program accessing SQLite database.

The table is very simple, two columns, ID and Age.

If I `SELECT Age FROM Table WHERE ID=23`, that would yield only a result.

So how can I put the age of that person into a int variable?

Edit: This [blog](http://milky.manishsinha.net/2009/03/30/sqlite-with-c/) provides a great introduction (with source code).

Comment: Did you study http://sqlite.org/quickstart.html ?

Comment: still trying to understand the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the reference. It will be something like:

```
ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, "SELECT Age FROM Table WHERE ID=23", -1, &stmt, &e);

if (sqlite3_step (stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    age = sqlite3_column_int (stmt, 0);
}
```